# Renaming all constraint names with user defined names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I query the database for all types of constraints such as Primary Key,Foreign Key, Unique Key, and Default Constraint, and rename its system generate name to a name in following format:

- PK_ColumnName1_ColumnName2
- FK_ColumnName1
- UK_ColumnName1_ColumnName2
- DF_ColumnName1

Comment: You should be aware that constraint names need to be unique across the entire schema. If there's a possibility of two tables having, say, primary keys consisting of columns with the same names, your proposed scheme will break. I'd suggest including the table name in the constraint names also.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tbl.name TableName, col.name ColName, ck.name ConstraintName, ck.definition ConstraintDefinition  ,' exec sp_rename [' +ck.name + '] , [DF_' + col.name + ']' SqlQuery 
FROM sys.default_constraints ck 
INNER JOIN sys.tables tbl 
on ck.parent_object_id = tbl.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col 
on tbl.object_id = col.object_id 
and ck.parent_column_id = col.column_id
```

This is for default constraints

use sys.key_constraints 
ans sys.foreign_keys

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a little more detailed and it too is specific to default constraints.

```
select      quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(o.name) as table_name,
        dc.name as default_name,
        'DF_' + o.name + '_' + c.name as new_default_name,
        'execute sp_rename ''' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + dc.name + ''', ''' + 'DF_' + o.name + '_' + c.name + ''' , ''OBJECT'' -- ' + s.name + '.' + o.name + '' as rename_script
from        sys.default_constraints as dc
join        sys.objects as o
    join        sys.schemas as s
    on          o.schema_id = s.schema_id
on          o.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
join        sys.columns as c
on          o.object_id = c.object_id
and         c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
where       dc.name like 'DF[_][_]%[_][_]%[_][_]%' -- DF__AlertType__Creat__10F7245D
and         o.type = 'u'
and         o.is_ms_shipped = 0
order by    s.name,
            o.name
```